# Python: mixed scenario regex

Tags: python, regex

I've been wrestling with this for a while and have come up just short of empty handed.

I am parsing a file into a pandas dataframe before dumping it to mysql and I have a set of lines with variations such as this:

```
523421 F-INV PROC 11/01 01:00:00
634312 MA-BAREAUTH 11/01 01:00:00
523421 MK-PERM YEAR 11/01 01:00:00
123512 G5-FSB 3.00 11/01 01:00:00
864982 JA-PAREN 4.25* 11/01 01:00:00
934821 4.00 11/01 01:00:00
620021 I-MAS DIN 5.25* 11/01 01:00:00
969722 MS-DARE .35 11/01 01:00:00
```

I am trying to translate each line into 4 groups regardless of a group being empty or not. Thus far I've made progress with the following regex, however it doesn't work if there is no \d.\d{2} match before the datestamp:

`(\d{6}).([^\d]*).([^\s][\.]\d+[\*]*).(\d{2}\/\d{2}\s\d{2}\:\d{2}\:\d{2})`

The idea is to group a line like

`969722 MS-DARE 1.35 11/01 01:00:00`

like this:

`969722` `MS-DARE` `1.35` `11/01 01:00:00`

This works on a line such as
`969722 MS-DARE 1.35 11/01 01:00:00` but breaks when group2 has a space in it such as:

`969722 MS-DARE PIN .35 11/01 01:00:00` which I want to group like `969722` `MS-DARE PIN` `1.35` `11/01 01:00:00`

Overall, the endgoal is to have all of these variations groups such as:

`523421` `F-INV PROC` `.95` `11/01 01:00:00`

`634312` `MA-BAREAUTH`  `11/01 01:00:00`

`523421` `MK-PERM YEAR`  `11/01 01:00:00`

`123512` `G5-FSB` `3.00` `11/01 01:00:00`

`864982` `JA-PAREN` `4.25*` `11/01 01:00:00`

`934821`  `4.00` `11/01 01:00:00`

`620021` `I-MAS DIN` `5.25*` `11/01 01:00:00`

`969722` `MS-DARE` `.35` `11/01 01:00:00`

How do I take all of these variations into account so that I always have 4 groups and if there's an amount like 3.00 or .35 present, it is group 3 or empty otherwise?

UPDATE:

https://regex101.com/r/lL8rIj/1/

Getting closer here, but I need an empty group 3 for each match if no amount present..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you could use

```
^                                      # start of line
(?P<group1>\d+)\s                      # capture numbers, match whitespace
(?P<group2>(?:(?!\d*\.\d+|\d{2}/).)+)? # capture as long as the formats 
                                       # of group 3 and 4 are not met  
                                       # the group is optional
(?P<group3>\d*\.\d+\*?)?\s+            # format of group 3...
(?P<group4>\d+/\d+.+)                  # ... and 4 respectively
$                                      # end of line
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/XFJlAr/2/).

---

In `Python` and `pandas` this would be:

```
import re, pandas as pd

string = """
864982 JA-PAREN 4.25* 11/01 01:00:00
934821 4.00 11/01 01:00:00
620021 I-MAS DIN 5.25* 11/01 01:00:00
969722 MS-DARE AUT .35 11/01 01:00:00
523421 F-INV PROC 11/01 01:00:00
634312 MA-BAREAUTH 11/01 01:00:00
523421 MK-PERM YEAR 11/01 01:00:00
123512 G5-FSB 3.00 11/01 01:00:00
"""

rx = re.compile(r'''
    ^
    (?P<group1>\d+)\s
    (?P<group2>(?:(?!\d*\.\d+|\d{2}/).)+)?
    (?P<group3>\d*\.\d+\*?)?\s+
    (?P<group4>\d+/\d+.+)
    $''', re.VERBOSE | re.MULTILINE)

records = ((m.group(1), m.group(2).rstrip() if m.group(2) else None, 
            m.group(3), m.group(4)) 
            for m in rx.finditer(string))

df = pd.DataFrame(records)
print(df)
```

---

This yields

```
        0             1      2               3
0  864982      JA-PAREN  4.25*  11/01 01:00:00
1  934821          None   4.00  11/01 01:00:00
2  620021     I-MAS DIN  5.25*  11/01 01:00:00
3  969722   MS-DARE AUT    .35  11/01 01:00:00
4  523421    F-INV PROC   None  11/01 01:00:00
5  634312   MA-BAREAUTH   None  11/01 01:00:00
6  523421  MK-PERM YEAR   None  11/01 01:00:00
7  123512        G5-FSB   3.00  11/01 01:00:00
```

Comment: This solution was the simplest for me to decipher and implement into the rest of my regex monster. Thanks Jan!

Comment: @oorahduc: Glad to help.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
import re
s = ['523421 F-INV PROC 11/01 01:00:00', '634312 MA-BAREAUTH 11/01 01:00:00', '523421 MK-PERM YEAR 11/01 01:00:00', '123512 G5-FSB 3.00 11/01 01:00:00', '864982 JA-PAREN 4.25* 11/01 01:00:00', '934821 4.00 11/01 01:00:00', '620021 I-MAS DIN 5.25* 11/01 01:00:00', '969722 MS-DARE .35 11/01 01:00:00']
final_s = [re.split('\s(?=[\d\W])|(?<=[\d\W])\s', i) for i in s]
```

Output:

```
[['523421', 'F-INV PROC', '11/01', '01:00:00'], 
['634312', 'MA-BAREAUTH', '11/01', '01:00:00'], 
['523421', 'MK-PERM YEAR', '11/01', '01:00:00'], 
['123512', 'G5-FSB', '3.00', '11/01', '01:00:00'], 
['864982', 'JA-PAREN', '4.25*', '11/01', '01:00:00'], 
['934821', '4.00', '11/01', '01:00:00'], 
['620021', 'I-MAS DIN', '5.25*', '11/01', '01:00:00'], 
['969722', 'MS-DARE', '.35', '11/01', '01:00:00']]
```

Comment: This gives me some ideas, but `['934821', '4.00', '11/01', '01:00:00']` would need to be `['934821', '', '4.00', '11/01 01:00:00']` .. hm.

Answer (score 1):

I want to propose [the next solution](http://rextester.com/YLZPC79048):

```
import re

data = """
864982 JA-PAREN 4.25* 11/01 01:00:00
934821 4.00 11/01 01:00:00
620021 I-MAS DIN 5.25* 11/01 01:00:00
969722 MS-DARE AUT .35 11/01 01:00:00
969722 MS-DARE 99/99 AUT .35 11/01 01:00:00
523421 F-INV PROC 11/01 01:00:00
634312 MA-BAREAUTH 11/01 01:00:00
523421 MK-PERM YEAR 11/01 01:00:00
523421 MK-PERM 3. YEAR 11/01 01:00:00
123512 G5-FSB 3.00 11/01 01:00:00
"""

rx = re.compile(r"""
  ^
  (\d+)
  (?:
    \s([a-z].*[a-z])
    \s(\d?\.\d+)\*?\s
   |(?:
      \s([a-z].*[a-z])(\s)
     |(\s)(\d*\.\d+)\*?\s
    )
  )
  (\d\d(?:[/\s:]\d\d){4})
  $
""", re.I | re.M | re.X)

for m in rx.finditer(data):
  print(tuple(e for e in m.groups() if e))
```

The result:

```
('864982', 'JA-PAREN', '4.25', '11/01 01:00:00')
('934821', ' ', '4.00', '11/01 01:00:00')
('620021', 'I-MAS DIN', '5.25', '11/01 01:00:00')
('969722', 'MS-DARE AUT', '.35', '11/01 01:00:00')
('969722', 'MS-DARE 99/99 AUT', '.35', '11/01 01:00:00')
('523421', 'F-INV PROC', ' ', '11/01 01:00:00')
('634312', 'MA-BAREAUTH', ' ', '11/01 01:00:00')
('523421', 'MK-PERM YEAR', ' ', '11/01 01:00:00')
('523421', 'MK-PERM 3. YEAR', ' ', '11/01 01:00:00')
('123512', 'G5-FSB', '3.00', '11/01 01:00:00')
```

Comment: Thanks Andrei. I went with Jan's solution but I do like the way you've done this. Jan's was just simpler to integrate with the rest of what I was doing.